# How to minify React and ES6 using Gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-uglify

I am new to using gulp, and am currently having an issue trying to minify my React files using `gulp-uglify` i was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out with my gulp task...

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    react = require('gulp-react'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('transform', function() {
    return gulp.src(_paths.app.js + '**/*.{jsx,js}')
        .pipe(react({ harmony: false, es6module: true })).pipe(babel())
        .pipe(concat('app.idea.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(_paths.build.js))
        .pipe(rename('app.idea.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(_paths.build.js));
});
```

There may be a better way to doing what i am trying to accomplish, or perhaps this is not ideal and I am open to suggestions on that. However, what I am attempting to accomplish is bundle all of my JSX and JS files into one JS file. Once it has been bundled I would like to minify the bundled file. Unfortunately I am receiving an error: `GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript` when I try to preform the uglify (I only have two JSX files currently).

I know that the bundling is working properly as my `app.idea.js` is being compiled as expected. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: 'gulp-concat' is not bundling. How do you expect it to work with modules? Use Webpack or whatever.

Comment: 'Unfortunately I am receiving an error' - sharing the error might be useful

Comment: @FuzzyTree - I understand what you are say, but the actual error itself is just as useful lol. Sorry, I forgot to include it... The original question has been updated.

Comment: @estus - `gulp-concat` is bundling with no issues. Is there a reason you are suggesting Webpack over Gulp?

Comment: They are apples and oranges. For full-fledged ES6 development concatting is not enough. But if it works for you, it's ok. Any way, the question cannot be answered, it's not clear why the error is there, what Babel configuration and output code look like. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @estus - I would be more than happy to update my question with any information that you feel you need. I didn't think it would be productive copying in my entire solution if it was something simple that i was overlooking and I know that everyone has their own flavor.  Like i said, I am just getting my feet wet the gulp world... Feel free to let me know though.

Comment: I would say that babel configuration (babelrc) in the question would be good for starters. Posting a link to git repo that can replicate the problem and contains unminified bundle file would be probably enough.

Comment: @estus - I am not using a babel configuration file. Should I be?

Comment: Of course. What is your ES6 code transpiled to if you haven't configured Babel? If there's ES6 in the output, Uglify won't be able to parse it

Comment: @estus - Honeslty have just been working it out as I go... I havent worked with es6 specifically and again... getting my feet wet. Well then i guess i need to do a little bit more research on what i need in my babelrc... lol thanks! Hopefully that is my issue

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at existing React+Babel boilerplates/starter kits on Github, there's a plenty of them and there's a lot to learn from. And usually they use Webpack for bundling, just because it is a dedicated tool for that (it may be optionally augmented with Gulp as well).

Comment: [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is made by Facebook, and is the simplest way to get up and running with React and ES6. Gulp might be capable of this, but it's a lot of work, and I don't see any benefit over the more well established methods.